# Need clarification on Dust js array

Tags: json, dust.js

Am new to dust template and to know the solution for this problem

I would like to iterate through this view context and get only the relative and friends arrays  first item.

```
{
  Relative: "ravi",
  friends: [
    { name: "Moe", age: 37 },
    { name: "Larry", age: 39 },
    { name: "Curly", age: 35 }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish using the `@eq` helper, available in the LinkedIn fork of Dust.

```
{Relative}{~n}
{#friends}
  {@eq key=0 value="{$idx}" type="number"}
    {name} {age}
  {/eq}
{/friends}
```

You still loop through the entire array, but only output name and age if the array index (`$idx`) is `0`.

Comment: Getting this error when i tried this code
SyntaxError: Expected buffer, comment, partial, reference, section or special but "{" found.

Comment: @BabuArumugam Try this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smfoote/z9mjM/1/ - you need to have dustjs as well as dustjs-helpers for the `{@eq}` helper to work.

Comment: I would like to know more about dust helper functions, if possible give me some good examples

Comment: This is probably (currently) the best place to see what helpers are available: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers/blob/master/lib/dust-helpers.js